# Intentionally blank field causing System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

- My company has a custom, multi-select picklist field for adding
  contacts to various campaigns.
- If a value is de-selected(unselected?) from that field they'd like
  the contact automatically removed from the corresponding campaign.
- When attempting to remove the contact from all selected campaigns I
  get a null pointer exception but this type of action happens often among users.
- I have only included 2 of the 17 conditional statements(only variance is City name) for readability because I assume whatever changes apply to one apply to all.
- I'm not even sure if this is a error I have made or if it is
  intended functionality that I need to try to work around(if
  possible).

  ```
  public void deleteContactFromCampaign(List<Contact> triggerNew, List<Contact> triggerOld, Map<Id, Contact> triggerNewMap, Map<Id, Contact>triggerOldMap){

  List<String> campaignIdsForDelete = new List<String>();

  List<CampaignMember> membersToDelete = new List<CampaignMember>();



  for(Contact C : triggerNew){
  Contact oldCon = triggerOldMap.get(C.Id);
  Contact newCon = triggerNewMap.get(C.Id);





      //Conditions and logic for deleting campaign members
      if((!newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis') || newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null) && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis')){
         camp =[SELECT name, Id FROM Campaign WHERE name LIKE '%Indianapolis%' and isActive = true LIMIT 1];
          campaignIdsForDelete.add(camp.Id);
      }

      if((!newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Tulsa') || newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null) && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Tulsa')){
          camp =[SELECT name, Id FROM Campaign WHERE name LIKE '%Tulsa%' and isActive = true LIMIT 1];
          campaignIdsForDelete.add(camp.Id);
      }

      if(campaignIdsForDelete.size() > 0){
      for(integer i=0; i<campaignIdsForDelete.size(); i++){
          membersToDelete.add([SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId = :C.Id AND CampaignId = :campaignIdsForDelete[i] AND Status != 'Responded']);
      }
  }
  }
  delete membersToDelete;
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the following solution.  Thank you guys for the idea to handle the null issue before I started checking for the fields contents.  That's what gave me the idea

```
if(newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c != null){
            List<CampaignMember> deleteAll = [SELECT Id FROM Campaignmember WHERE ContactId = :C.Id AND Status != 'Responded'];
            delete deleteAll;    
        }else{
if((!newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis') || newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null) && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis')){
   camp =[SELECT name, Id FROM Campaign WHERE name LIKE '%Indianapolis%' and isActive = true LIMIT 1];
    campaignIdsForDelete.add(camp.Id);
}//etc
```

Comment: FYI - you could simplify lines 2 and 3 to : `delete [SELECT Id FROM Campaignmember WHERE ContactId = :C.Id AND Status != 'Responded'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the logic - it should evaluate left to right, so check for NULL first. Or do the NULL check first, and only do the contains once you know it isn't NULL:

```
if((newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null || !newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis') ) && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis')){
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get a debug log to see which line has the null pointer? My first thought is that newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c is null. Doing a contains on a null will throw an NPE. You could try swapping the or so that contains doesn't run if it's null and you'll also want to check that the old value isn't null, for example instead of:

```
if((!newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis') || newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null) && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis')){
```

do this:

```
if((newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c == null ||!newCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis')) && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c != null && oldCon.RCRA_Seminar_Invites__c.contains('Indianapolis')){
```